# Accessing objects in semantic_fieds_for loop / formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

Model has accepts_nested_attributes_for for the relation and the form is as follows:

```
= semantic_form_for @obj, :url => path do |f|  
  =  f.inputs do
    = f.input :name
    = f.semantic_fields_for :photos do |p|
      = p.inputs :desc
  = f.buttons
```

The form works well and everything is fine. However, I would like to display each photo near the field, so the user could se which picture she is going to annotate. Is there anyway, to access photo.id inside the fields_for loop?

Edit:

Is there any way to alter the order in which photos fields will be rendered in this example. As far as I can tell till now, that order is pretty random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this was easy enough, the object is accesible by:

```
p.object
```

:-)

Second part of the question is solved with:

```
default_scope order(...)
```

Comment: Where did you find this?
I've been looking for this for ages.